# Replication of MySQL database between docker swarm clusters

Tags: mysql, docker, database-replication, docker-swarm

I have two docker swarm clusters. Each of the clusters has a container with MySQL-server. I need to implement replication between those MySQL-servers stored on different swarm clusters.

Perhaps someone has already worked with such a setup?

I need to do something like this

[image: something like this]

Comment: Please post any code that you've already tried.

Comment: I tried to use Weave Net to implement connections between clusters, but it's didn't work( I don't know why)..Now I try to run 'bortels/socat' container on each of the clusters and use it as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the current offering of swarm alone is not enough to address this problem.
You can use SQL cluster or galera along with Swarm for this purpose.